# How to use the \pderiv and \D macros of the cool package with subscripts?

Tags: math-mode

Is it possible to use the \pderiv or \D macros of the latex cool package when the derivative order and the variable uses a subscript?

This fails with a "double subscript" error:

```
\D[a_1]{f}{x_1}
```

The output should look like this:

```
\frac{d^{a_1} f}{d x_1^{a_1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cool` has a really complicated way to proceed. Adding a pair of braces doesn't suffice and neither two pairs of braces do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cool}
\begin{document}
\[
\D[{{{a_1}}}]{f}{x_1}
\D[\bgroup a_1\egroup]{f}{x_1}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, instead, one pair suffices.

[image]

Comment: Wow.  I could have been guessing a long time before I came up with that one.

Comment: So this is more or less the same as the answer I wanted to post to my own question:

Within the command `\COOL@derivative` in the file `cool.sty` (lines 2045 to 2451) replace every occurence of commands like

    \a^\b
with

    \a^{\b}
and you get the desired output. Apply the changes to a local copy which resdes in the same folder as your .tex file.